# Capybara not loading or adding Extensions when Chrome browser is opened

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, rubygems, capybara

I am trying to automate opening of Chrome browser with extension/add-on "mod headers" so that I can send url with http headers, user agents etc.

Problem is my script (code snippet given below) is opening up the Chrome browser without extension/add-on "mod headers", not sure what I am doing wrong? Please help

```
env.rb:


require 'rspec'
require 'cucumber'
require 'capybara'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'base64'

Capybara.app_host = "http://google.com"

settings = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))+ "/../../config/settings.yml")
puts settings.inspect
puts settings["browser"]

case settings["browser"]
  when "CHROME"
    chrome_extensions = []
    my_capabilities = Hash.new
    # chrome_extension_path = '/Users/Duncan/Desktop/Browser_Testing/extension_1_2_4.crx'
    # puts '#{chrome_extension_path}'
    begin
        File.open('/Users/Duncan/Desktop/Browser_Testing/extension_1_2_4.crx', "rb") do |file|
        chrome_extensions << Base64.encode64(file.read.chomp)
        puts 'over it is...'
        end
    rescue Exception => e
      raise "ERROR: Couldn't File.read or Base64.encode64 a Chrome extension: #{e.message}"
    end
    # Append the extensions to your capabilities hash
      my_capabilities.merge!({'chrome.extensions' => chrome_extensions})
      caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(my_capabilities)
      Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
     #Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :switches => ["--load-extension=/Users/chinmayajb/Desktop/MPM_Testing/extension_1_2_4.crx"])
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps)
    end
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
end
```

Comment: Are the extensions you are using loaded from the Chrome Web Store, or by going to developer mode and using "Load Unpacked Extension"?  I'm not familiar with Capybara, but in chrome there are several things that might cause extensions not to load. One is trying to use an unpacked extension when not in developer mode or not on the same user profile that you used when you added the extension.  Another is loading a different chrome profile with Capybara than the extension was intended for (or perhaps Capybara is not logging into a profile at all, I can't tell from your script.)

Comment: Also, you might not be waiting long enough for the extensions to load, they are not available the instant chrome starts.

Comment: Thanks for your response petewil-G, much appreciated. I got the code working for Firefox using almost similar logic. However i would be interested to know how to load specific profile in Chrome (which has extensions loaded already)? I am particular about Capybara, can use Watir or selenium too (Or) generic code to load extension to the Chrome driver on the run with Packed (*.crx) package.

Comment: Hi there,  Is it possible to share a snippet of code for adding extension to Chrome browser and launching it using any of the webdrivers (Selenium/Watir/Capybara). I have tried multiple times and failed so far.

Comment: `--load-extensions` loads an unpacked extension, not a `crx` file.

Answer (score 0):

This Should work for loading the extension using Ruby Capybara on Chrome browser:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome({'chromeOptions' 
    => 
    {'extensions' => Base64.strict_encode64(

    File.open('C:\Workspace\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\extension.crx','rb').read
    )]}})
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
        Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, 
        :desired_capabilities => caps)
    end
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to add an extension from a .crx file. You shouldn't need to use `File.open`.

Try adding it via `options`, like this:

```rb
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_extension(Rails.root.join('spec', 'chrome_extensions', 'react-devtools.crx'))
    options.add_extension(Rails.root.join('spec', 'chrome_extensions', 'redux-devtools.crx'))

    chrome_options = {
      browser: :chrome,
      options: options
    }

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, chrome_options)
  end
```

(example from https://medium.com/@ccschmitz/upgrade-your-js-debugging-in-capybara-w-browser-extensions-1b34fce4d229)